# Assigning Random Values to Each of the Cells in a Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code here that with the click of a button it randomly selects from a list of values entered into a text box, I have managed to manipulate it so that it enters the randomly generated value into the first cell of a table, but I was wondering if it was possible with the click of a button to randomly assign a different value to each of the cells in a row? Here is my code:

```js
 var rnd = function () {
  var loader, things;
  loader = document.getElementById('ajax-loader');
  loader.style.display = 'inline';
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function () {
   var thing;
   loader.style.display = 'none';
   thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = things[thing];
  }, 500);
 };
 
 // a little functionality for erin foley...

 // save the things the user entered
 document.getElementById('things').addEventListener('blur', function ( evt ) {
  window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked'] = this.value
 })

 // use the user’s saved things
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ( evt ) {
  var things = window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked']
  if ( things ) {
   document.getElementById('things').value = things
  }
 })
```

```css
 fieldset input {
  display: block;
 }
 #result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
 }
 #ajax-loader {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
 }

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
 }
 td,
 th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
     text-align: center
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B &amp; B</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Green</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  <fieldset>
   <label>
    <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
   </label>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
   <img id="ajax-loader" src="http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/random/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Picking...">
  </p>
 </form>
</td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: Even though an error shows the snippet still works.

Here is some code that does exactly what I want the above snippet to do:

```js
var round1 = ['Forrest Gump', 'Tim Thomas', 'Pamila Henryson', 'Lotus Hobbes', 'Jerry Sparks', 'Kenneth Ingham'];
var round2 = ['Cyril Willard', 'Gale Frank', 'Aveline Derricks', 'Darcey Bullock', 'Jaiden Deering', 'Glenn Benn'];
var round3 = ['George Washington', 'John Adams', 'Tom Jefferson', 'James Madison', 'James Monroe', 'John Quincy Adams'];
/* game is a multidimensional array. 
|  Each element is an array(sub-array).
|  Each sub-array is a row in a table.
|  Each element of a sub-array is a cell.
*/
var game = [round1, round2, round3];
// count will be incremented per click of button
var count = 0;

function rounds(n, obj) {
  
// Determine which sub-array to use
var array = obj[n - 1];
  
// Determine the specific <tr>
var row = 'tr:nth-of-type(' + n + ')';
 
// Reference each <td> cell of the <tr> row
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('tbody ' + row + ' td');
  
// Cell count
var x = 0;
  
// Separate each element of sub-array
array = array.slice(0);
  
// while loop establishes limits and iteration
while (array.length > 0 && x < cells.length) {

// Get a randomly generated number 
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

/* On each iteration...
|  ...insert the element of sub-array...
|  ...that was determined by a randomly...
|  ...generated index number.
*/
cells[x].innerHTML = array[randomIndex];

// Increment cell count
x++;

// Join all of the cells together in it's new order
array.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
 }
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <body>
<table id="example" class="display" align=center>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <th>Blue</th>
    <th>B &amp; B</th>
    <th>Gold</th>
    <th>Green</th>
    <th>Gryphons</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="padding:25px" align=center>
<!-- This button's attribute event has a incremental counter, so each successive click will change the count parameter -->
<button type="button" onclick="count++;rounds(count, game)">Simulate to next round</button>

</div>
 </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: If you've got code that does exactly what you want, what's the question here?

Comment: The code that does exactly what I want can't randomly select from a list of names in a textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ChippeRockTheMurph

It looks like the core of your question is: " it was possible with the click of a button to randomly assign a different value to each of the cells in a row?"

This shouldn't be too hard, but the way you have this written at the moment you'll have problems.  Note:

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = things[thing];

however, every one of your td's has a div  with id "result".  getElementById() only returns one element (and, in theory, only one element in an entire document should have a particular id value).

You might be better doing something like:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('div[id="foo"]');

for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
    thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
    list.item(index).innerHTML = things[thing];
}
```

However, it would be even better to not use an id, so your HTML would be something like

```
<td><div class="js-result"></div></td>
```

and then you could do something like:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.js-result');
```

Which would be cleaner.

Here's a functioning example:

```js
var rnd = function () {
  var things;
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function () {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('.js-result');
    
            for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
                var thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
                list.item(index).innerHTML = things[thing];
            }
  }, 500);
 };
```

```css
fieldset input {
  display: block;
 }
 .result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
 }

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
 }
 td,
 th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
     text-align: center
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

```html
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B &amp; B</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Green</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  <fieldset>
   <label>
    <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
   </label>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
  </p>
 </form>
</td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Does this help?

Comment: Is it possible to give each cell in the first row a different name, instead of randomly assigning from the same group for each cell which will result in several cells having the same name?

Comment: Sure.  In that case I think you'd just need to keep another list of the names you have already used (or look at the values already in the table), and generate a new random value in that case.  You'd need to make sure there are more names than cells so you do not get stuck in an infinite loop!